# Для чего объявляют коллекцию final в методе java?

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции, final

Который раз натыкаюсь на код на гитхабе вроде:

```
public List<Integer> meth(){
 final ArrayList <Integer> arl = new ArrayList()<>;
 ... //Какая-то реализация
      return arl;
}
```

Или так:

```
public map <Integer, Integer> meth(){
 final HashMap <Integer, Integer> hmp = new HashMap()<>;
 ... //Какая-то реализация
return hmp; 
}
```

Где-то в подсознании, у меня есть отдаленное понимание, что сие делается для многопоточного программирования. Но что это даст?

**Вопрос**: зачем ряд программистов на гитхабе создавая локальную коллекцию делают её `final`?

Comment: Это не имеет отношения ни к многопоточности, ни к коллекциям. Вы уже прочитали документацию по служебному слову `final`?

Comment: @Igor, Несомненно. Для объектов - делается постоянная ссылка, которую нельзя переназначить.

Comment: Что Вам непонятно в этом предложении?

Comment: Зачем делать final внутри метода? Разве кто-то собирается там что-то переназначать?

Comment: Я гуглил - ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Ко всему сказанному выше добавлю, что использование ключевого слова final для локальных переменных, помимо повышения читаемости кода, помогает компилятору статически оптимизировать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что значит "кто-то собирается там что-то переназначать"? Может и собирается, Вы же не знаете, что в голове у того, кто писал этот код. Программист, использующий `final` в объявлении переменных и параметров, уважает тех, кто будет читать его код, и стремится облегчить им жизнь. После такой декларации мы уверены, что значение переменной будет присвоено только один раз и не сможет измениться.

Comment: То есть, это просто удобство? Никакого функционала это не несёт? Я просто выбрасывал final - код продолжал работать.